# Cannot access protected property in trait

Tags: php, oop, variables, scope, traits

Writing some PHP. After some debugging I reduced my wonderful behaviour to that code:

```
trait T1 {
     function a1() { return $this->var; }
}
trait T2 {
     use T1;
     function a2() { return T1::a1(); }
}
class A {
     use T2;
     protected $var = 3;
}

$a = new A;
echo $a->a2();
```

This code works as long $var in class A is defined as public; as I wanna have that protected (just to make it nice) I stumbled over an error *Fatal error: Cannot access protected property B::$var in ... on line 5*

Why does that happen in this case? Does the T1::a1 do a scope change to be kind of "outside of class"?

Comment: "I wanna have that protected (just to make it nice)" lol!

Comment: Same result if you `return $this->a1();` in `a2()` in `T2`?

Comment: sorry, where are you constructing `$b` in this code? (either fix your code to make that $a, which I assume you meant to do, or introduce the declaration and initialisation of $b)

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this one works: http://3v4l.org/iOFSt Might be property name `var`, or the static-like call to `a1()`. Works with `var` as prop name too: http://3v4l.org/TNcVA

Comment: Ooooh. You're calling the static method of a trait directly. Never a good idea. And probably the reason. Weird results: http://3v4l.org/PQK4g

Comment: Thank you all for your hints. Example actually works when using no :: operator, doesn't work for my more complex project. There must be something else entirely broken. Solved it by writing "use x as y" and changing order and location of trait inclusions. Sorry, can't figure out what I broke there.

Comment: Btw: The :: operator is kind of "as specified" to access specific instances when using parent:: etc. Seems like I miss-interpreted that a bit in trait context ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling the static method of a trait directly. Never a good idea.

You shouldn't use traits names anywhere but in the `use` statement in the class.

If you call `a1()` as a method of `$this`, it works fine: http://3v4l.org/TNcVA

```
trait T1 {
    function a1() {
        return $this->var;
    }
}
trait T2 {
    use T1;
    function a2() {
        return $this->a1();
    }
}
class A {
    use T2;
    protected $var = 3;
}

$a = new A;
echo $a->a2();
```

Comment: Ok never a good idea, but it will be nice to hear some explanation on why

Comment: PHP docs say: traits are a "copy'n'paste mechanism to build classes". Outside the compiler they don't exist. You can't detect where methods come from, what traits have been loaded etc. They're just used to construct the class. That's why you shouldn't use them anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using traits, don't treat them as static classes. Don't use

```
function a2() { return T1::a1(); }
```

but simply use:

```
function a2() { return $this->a1(); }
```

If you call them as if they're static class functionality `$this` becomes a meaningless keyword and `a1()` will have no idea what you're trying to do when you hit `$this->var`